# TypeScript infer type by its unique field

Tags: typescript, types, type-inference, type-safety

I have a composite type called `IncomingMessage`

```js
export type IncomingMessage =
  | MessageText
  | MessageGameStarted
//| ... rest

export type IncomingMessageType = 
  | IncomingMessage['messageType']
```

each member of type `IncomingMessage` is represented as an interface with unique key `messageType`

```js
interface MessageText {
  messageType: MessageType.TEXT
  content: string
}

interface MessageGameStarted {
  messageType: MessageType.GAME_STARTED
}

// ... rest
```

Then, I have a class `Network` that listens for those messages and delegates them to appropriate handlers. You can add handlers to `Network` depending on `IncomingMessageType`

```js
type Handler<T extends IncomingMessage> = (message: T) => any
type Handlers = {[messageType in IncomingMessageType]?: Handler</*???*/>}

class Network {
    private readonly handlers: Handlers = {}
    
    on<T extends IncomingMessage>(messageType: T['messageType'], handler: Handler<T>) {
        this.handlers[messageType] = handler
        return this
    }
}
```

What I need to accompish:

1. method `Network.on(messageType, handler)` should be type-safe: when you type

```js
network.on(MessageType.TEXT, message => {
   // message type should be MessageText
})
```

typescript should infer type of 'message' parameter based on 'messageType' parameter

2. I should properly type `Handlers`. I want to be able to infer Handler generic from current messageType

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to extract the right message from the union with [`Extract`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#extracttype-union):

```
type Handler<T extends IncomingMessage> = (message: T) => any
type Handlers = { [messageType in IncomingMessageType]?: Handler<Extract<IncomingMessage, { messageType: messageType }>>}

class Network {
    private readonly handlers: Handlers = {}
    
    on<T extends IncomingMessageType>(messageType: T, handler: Handler<Extract<IncomingMessage, { messageType: T }>>) {
        this.handlers[messageType] = handler as Handler<any>;
        return this
    }
}
```

You also have to change the signature of `on` to use the generic on the message type instead, as TypeScript cannot infer the message's type in the handler.

So now your `on` should work correctly:

```
new Network().on(MessageType.TEXT, message => {
    message
//  ^?
});
```

However you will notice that I have used an assertion when assigning the handler, and I don't think it is possible to get around it.

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/w1pgOW)